# Estimating a change in price caused by a change in dimensions

Tags: calculus

I am stuck on this problem - I really don't know how to set it up.

A soft drink can is $h$ centimeters tall and has a radius of $r$ cm. The cost of material in the can is $.0005$ cents per cm$^2$ and the soda itself costs $.001$ cents per cm$^3$. The cans are currently $9$ cm tall and have a radius of $4$ cm. Use calculus to estimate the effect on costs of increasing the radius by $0.4$ cm and decreasing the height by $0.7$ cm. Round your answer to $3$ decimals

I wanted to start this problem by integrating the formula $\pi r^2h$ in terms of $r$ and then $h$. So I found $2\pi rh$ and multiplied it by $.4$, the change in $r$, and then I found $\pi x^2$ and multiplied it by $.7$ and I can solve that but I don't know what the next step is. I don't know how to factor the costs into this whole thing, so can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You can estimate the changes of the surface and the volume by using the  [total derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_derivative).

The formula for the surface S is $S= 2\cdot \pi r^2+2\cdot \pi r\cdot h$

And the change of the surface is approximately

$dS\approx\frac{\partial S}{\partial r}dr +\frac{\partial S}{\partial h }dh$

$dS\approx (4\pi r+2\pi h)\cdot dr+2\pi r\cdot dh$

$dS\approx (4\pi\cdot 4+ 2\pi \cdot 9)\cdot 0.4+2\pi \cdot 4\cdot (-0.7)=25.13227$

The material cost increases by $0.0005\cdot 25.13227\approx 0.013$ cents.

The formula for the Volume V is $V=  \pi r^2\cdot h$

And the change of the volume is approximately

$dV\approx\frac{\partial V}{\partial r}dr +\frac{\partial V}{\partial h }dh$

$dV\approx 2\pi\cdot r\cdot h\cdot  dr+\pi\cdot r^2 \cdot dh$

$dV\approx 2\pi\cdot 4\cdot 9\cdot  0.4+\pi\cdot 4^2\cdot (-0.7) =55.29$

Thus the cost for the soda increases by $55.29\cdot 0.001\approx 0.055$ cents

In total the cost of the soft drink increases by approximately $0.068(=0.055+0.013)$ cents.

---

The approximation is maybe too rough. You can also calculate the difference of the costs. Let $S(r,h)$ be the surface with the radius r and the height h. Similar for $V(r,h)$ The the difference of the costs is

$S(4.4,8.3)\cdot 0.001+V(4.4,8.3)\cdot 0.0005-(S(4,9)\cdot 0.001+V(4,9)\cdot 0.0005)$

$=(\pi\cdot 4.4^2\cdot 8.3\cdot 0.001+(2\cdot \pi\cdot 4.4^2+2\cdot\pi\cdot 8.3\cdot 4.4)\cdot 0.0005)-(\pi\cdot 16\cdot 9\cdot 0.001+(2\cdot \pi\cdot 16+2\cdot\pi\cdot 36)\cdot 0.0005)=0.0646\approx 0.065$

Answer (score 0):

> Notice, for a cylinder:
>
> - $$\text{Volume cylinder}=\pi r^2h$$
> - $$\text{Surface area cylinder}=2\pi r(r+h)$$
>
> You can prove that using the function $f(x)=r$ where $r$ is the radius and rotate it around the x-axis, with the formula:
>
> - $$\text{Volume cylinder}=\pi\int_0^hr^2\space\text{d}x$$
> - $$\text{Surface area cylinder}=2\pi\int_0^hr\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}x}\left(r\right)\right)^2}\space\text{d}x+2\pi r^2$$

The can now costs:

$$\left(2\pi \cdot4\cdot(4+9)\right)\cdot0.0005+\left(\pi\cdot4^2\cdot9\right)\cdot0.001=\frac{49\pi}{250}\approx0.615752\dots$$

The new can costs:

$$\left(2\pi \cdot4.4\cdot(4.4+8.3)\right)\cdot0.0005+\left(\pi\cdot(4.4)^2\cdot8.3\right)\cdot0.001=\frac{27071\pi}{125000}\approx0.680368\dots$$

So, the difference is:

$$\frac{27071\pi}{125000}-\frac{49\pi}{250}=\frac{2571\pi}{125000}\approx0.0646163$$

Comment: i subtracted the two values you got and they were wrong

Comment: @Noah Oh, I don't see my mistake yet (if I actually maked it)! But what must the answer be (what do you think)?

Answer (score 0):

Although you have a precise answer to this problem, you have a function $p(r,h)$ of price depending on the height and radius. You don't require calculus to answer the problem. However they are asking you to use calculus to estimate. This usually means the following:

Having a function $z = f(x,y)$, and knowing the value of the function at a point $(x_0,y_0)$ you can approximate the function by a plane given by

$$z \approx \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}\Big|_{(x_0,y_0)}(x-x_0) + \dfrac{\partial f}{\partial y}\Big|_{(x_0,y_0)}(y-y_0).$$

With this plane you can approximate the actual function at a point $(x,y)$. The price function can be built as follows:
$$p(r,h)= \text{Price of can per area unit}\times\text{Area of can} + \text{Price of soda per volume unit}\times\text{Volume of can}.$$

The area of the can is simply $2\pi rh + 2\pi r^2$. And the volume is $\pi r^2 h$.